# Solving $\frac{dx}{dt} = A \frac{ (1-x)}{(t-t^2)} - \frac{(B*x -C*x^2)}{(t-t^2 )*(t-x)}$ (using wolfram/mathematica)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, mathematica, wolfram-alpha

I would like to solve the following non-linear ordinary differential equation:

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = A \frac{ (1-x)}{(t-t^2)} - \frac{(B*x -C*x^2)}{(t-t^2 )*(t-x)}$$

-I need an analytic solution.

-I don't know where to start (the 2 terms make it difficult), therefore I tried to use Wolfram-Alpha/ Mathematica. See [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=dx%2Fdt%20%3D%20A%20%281-x%29%2F%28t-t%5E2%29%20-%20%28B*x%20-C*x%5E2%29%2F%28%28t-t%5E2%20%29*%28t-x%29%29)

-It seems however that even Wolfram-Alpha / Mathematica is not able to solve it (computation time out).

-Can someone help me out?

Comment: Maybe you can use partial fraction decomposition to simplify the expression. But I'm not certain that would help much. I wouldn't be suprised Mathematica already tried that.

Comment: @Nihl For the 2nd term you mean?

Comment: It can also be used for the first. $\frac{1}{t-t^2}$ can be written as a combinaison of  $\frac{1}{1-t}$ and $\frac{1}{t}$.

Comment: @Nihl Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't work out.. wolfram can then still not solve it..

Comment: Did you use Wolfram-alpha AND Mathematica? They are not the same thing. I'm saying this because there is no "computation time out" on Mathematica. Mathematica is a software that runs on your computer (it's not online), therefore it doesn't impose time limits for computations.

Comment: @Integral Yes I know and I used both.. However, Mathematica also did not solve it..

Comment: I just tried your problem on Mathematica. It was solved almost instantly.

Comment: I'll post as an answer so you can check whether it's ok or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $u=t-x$ ,

Then $x=t-u$

$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=1-\dfrac{du}{dt}$

$\therefore1-\dfrac{du}{dt}=\dfrac{A(1-t+u)}{t-t^2}-\dfrac{B(t-u)-C(t-u)^2}{(t-t^2)u}$

$u-u\dfrac{du}{dt}=\dfrac{Au}{t}+\dfrac{Au^2}{t-t^2}+\dfrac{Cu^2+(B-2Ct)u+Ct^2-Bt}{t-t^2}$

$u-u\dfrac{du}{dt}=\dfrac{Au}{t}+\dfrac{(A+C)u^2+(B-2Ct)u+Ct^2-Bt}{t-t^2}$

$u\dfrac{du}{dt}=\dfrac{(A+C)u^2}{t^2-t}+\left(\dfrac{B-2Ct}{t^2-t}-\dfrac{A}{t}+1\right)u+\dfrac{Ct^2-Bt}{t^2-t}$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind.

In fact all Abel equation of the second kind can be transformed into Abel equation of the first kind.

Let $u=\dfrac{1}{v}$ ,

Then $\dfrac{du}{dt}=-\dfrac{1}{v^2}\dfrac{dv}{dt}$

$\therefore-\dfrac{1}{v^3}\dfrac{dv}{dt}=\dfrac{A+C}{(t^2-t)v^2}+\left(\dfrac{B-2Ct}{t^2-t}-\dfrac{A}{t}+1\right)\dfrac{1}{v}+\dfrac{Ct^2-Bt}{t^2-t}$

$\dfrac{dv}{dt}=-\dfrac{(Ct^2-Bt)v^3}{t^2-t}-\left(\dfrac{B-2Ct}{t^2-t}-\dfrac{A}{t}+1\right)v^2-\dfrac{(A+C)v}{t^2-t}$

Please follow the method in http://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijmms/2011/387429/#sec2

Comment: Using insights from this answer, I derived a parametric solution for `B = C = -A` and posted it under [Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85587/solving-fracdxdt-a-frac-1-xt-t2-fracbx-cx2t-t2/85653#85653).

Comment: Yes, Maple confirms the type: `DEtools[odeadvisor](eq,x(t));` gives `[_rational, [_Abel, 2nd type, class B]]` and class B is described more in this paper http://arxiv.org/pdf/math-ph/0001037.pdf in the appendix it gives a model ODE of this class and its solution.

Answer (score 4):

I tried to use Mathematica to solve your problem and it solved pretty fast. Here is what I've done.

[image: sol]

Comment: Could you please post the code you use as text? I tried your code using `DSolve[x'[t] == 
  A*(1 - x[t])/(t - t^2) - (B*x[t] - C*x[t]^2)/((t - t^2)*(t - x[t])),
  x[t], t]` but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: @Integral Same problem here..

Comment: @dreamer That is it, your code is right. I just try your code here and is working fine. Maybe the problem is the version you are using. Mathematica 10.0 is the one I use.

Comment: @Integral That's odd... I use 10.0 too. Mine indicates that it is running, but it doesn't get to anything.

Comment: Tested on my other computer which runs version 9 now too also without success. Weird stuff...

Comment: Really weird... maybe it has something to do with the computer configuration or the OS used. I really don't know, but I got the answer and shared with you guys here.

Comment: @Integral MMA should return a solution involving a constant of integration (i.e. `C[1]`) for the problem you gave. Would you be able to restart the kernel and try for this solution again?

Comment: @Integral  Please try back-substituting your solutions into the equation.  When I do so, I do not get `0`.

Comment: I just tried to solve again, and for some reason, it's running forever...Mathematica tricked me last time, but I don't have idea what happened. Does anyone know what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
ClearAll[A, B, Cc, x, t]
```

AsymptoticDSolveValue[
Derivative[1][x][t] == (A (1 - x[t]))/(t - t^2) - (
B x[t] - Cc x[t]^2)/((t - t^2) (t - x[t])), x[t], {t, A, 1}]

(*
C[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckAK6.png) + (-A +
t) (-((1 - C[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckAK6.png))/(-1 + A)) - ((-1 + 2 A) (1 - C[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckAK6.png)))/(-1 +
A)^2 - (A (B C[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckAK6.png) - Cc C[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckAK6.png)^2))/((A - A^2) (A - C
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckAK6.png))^2) + ((-1 + 2 A) (B C[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckAK6.png) - Cc C[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckAK6.png)^2))/((-1 + A)^2 A (A -
C[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckAK6.png))) - (-B C[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckAK6.png) + Cc C[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckAK6.png)^2)/((-1 + A) A (A - C[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckAK6.png))) -
A (-(((-1 + 2 A) (1 - C[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckAK6.png)))/((-1 + A)^2 A)) - (
B C[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckAK6.png) -
Cc C[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckAK6.png)^2)/((A - A^2) (A - C[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckAK6.png))^2) + ((-1 + 2 A) (B C[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckAK6.png) -
Cc C[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckAK6.png)^2))/((-1 + A)^2 A^2 (A - C[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckAK6.png)))))
*)

Mind the x0 is set be selection to A without any restriction. The order of the asymptotic expansion is set to the lowest nonzero one.

```
AsymptoticDSolveValue[
 Derivative[1][x][t] == (A (1 - x[t]))/(t - t^2) - (
   B x[t] - Cc x[t]^2)/((t - t^2) (t - x[t])), x[t], {t, A, 2}]
```

---

```
C[1] + ((-A + t) (-A^2 + A C[1] + A^2 C[1] + B C[1] - A C[1]^2 - 
    Cc C[1]^2))/((-A + A^2) (A - C[1])) + 
 1/(2 (-A + A^2)^2 (A - C[1])^3) (-A + t)^2 (-A^4 + A^5 - A^3 B + 
    3 A^3 C[1] - 2 A^4 C[1] - A^5 C[1] + 3 A^2 B C[1] - A^3 B C[1] + 
    A B^2 C[1] + 2 A^3 Cc C[1] - 3 A^2 C[1]^2 + 3 A^4 C[1]^2 - 
    3 A B C[1]^2 + 2 A^2 B C[1]^2 - 5 A^2 Cc C[1]^2 - 
    3 A B Cc C[1]^2 + A C[1]^3 + 2 A^2 C[1]^3 - 3 A^3 C[1]^3 + 
    B C[1]^3 - A B C[1]^3 + 4 A Cc C[1]^3 + B Cc C[1]^3 + 
    2 A Cc^2 C[1]^3 - A C[1]^4 + A^2 C[1]^4 - Cc C[1]^4 - Cc^2 C[1]^4)

AsymptoticDSolveValue[
 Derivative[1][x][t] == (A (1 - x[t]))/(t - t^2) - (
   B x[t] - Cc x[t]^2)/((t - t^2) (t - x[t])), x[t], {t, A, 3}]
___
C[1] + ((-A + t) (-A^2 + A C[1] + A^2 C[1] + B C[1] - A C[1]^2 - 
    Cc C[1]^2))/((-A + A^2) (A - C[1])) + 
 1/(2 (-A + A^2)^2 (A - C[1])^3) (-A + t)^2 (-A^4 + A^5 - A^3 B + 
    3 A^3 C[1] - 2 A^4 C[1] - A^5 C[1] + 3 A^2 B C[1] - A^3 B C[1] + 
    A B^2 C[1] + 2 A^3 Cc C[1] - 3 A^2 C[1]^2 + 3 A^4 C[1]^2 - 
    3 A B C[1]^2 + 2 A^2 B C[1]^2 - 5 A^2 Cc C[1]^2 - 
    3 A B Cc C[1]^2 + A C[1]^3 + 2 A^2 C[1]^3 - 3 A^3 C[1]^3 + 
    B C[1]^3 - A B C[1]^3 + 4 A Cc C[1]^3 + B Cc C[1]^3 + 
    2 A Cc^2 C[1]^3 - A C[1]^4 + A^2 C[1]^4 - Cc C[1]^4 - 
    Cc^2 C[1]^4) + 
 1/(6 (-A + A^2)^3 (A - C[1])^5) (-A + t)^3 (-2 A^6 + 3 A^7 - A^8 - 
    3 A^5 B + 6 A^6 B - A^4 B^2 - 2 A^6 Cc + 10 A^5 C[1] - 
    13 A^6 C[1] + 2 A^7 C[1] + A^8 C[1] + 13 A^4 B C[1] - 
    25 A^5 B C[1] + 3 A^3 B^2 C[1] - 6 A^4 B^2 C[1] + A^2 B^3 C[1] + 
    14 A^5 Cc C[1] - 8 A^6 Cc C[1] + 8 A^4 B Cc C[1] - 
    20 A^4 C[1]^2 + 20 A^5 C[1]^2 + 5 A^6 C[1]^2 - 5 A^7 C[1]^2 - 
    23 A^3 B C[1]^2 + 42 A^4 B C[1]^2 - A^5 B C[1]^2 - 
    3 A^2 B^2 C[1]^2 + 12 A^3 B^2 C[1]^2 + 2 A B^3 C[1]^2 - 
    37 A^4 Cc C[1]^2 + 30 A^5 Cc C[1]^2 + 4 A^6 Cc C[1]^2 - 
    24 A^3 B Cc C[1]^2 + 13 A^4 B Cc C[1]^2 - 7 A^2 B^2 Cc C[1]^2 - 
    8 A^4 Cc^2 C[1]^2 + 20 A^3 C[1]^3 - 10 A^4 C[1]^3 - 
    20 A^5 C[1]^3 + 10 A^6 C[1]^3 + 21 A^2 B C[1]^3 - 
    36 A^3 B C[1]^3 + 3 A^4 B C[1]^3 + A B^2 C[1]^3 - 
    6 A^2 B^2 C[1]^3 + 49 A^3 Cc C[1]^3 - 42 A^4 Cc C[1]^3 - 
    15 A^5 Cc C[1]^3 + 27 A^2 B Cc C[1]^3 - 30 A^3 B Cc C[1]^3 - 
    2 A B^2 Cc C[1]^3 + 24 A^3 Cc^2 C[1]^3 - 6 A^4 Cc^2 C[1]^3 + 
    12 A^2 B Cc^2 C[1]^3 - 10 A^2 C[1]^4 - 5 A^3 C[1]^4 + 
    25 A^4 C[1]^4 - 10 A^5 C[1]^4 - 10 A B C[1]^4 + 16 A^2 B C[1]^4 - 
    3 A^3 B C[1]^4 - 35 A^2 Cc C[1]^4 + 26 A^3 Cc C[1]^4 + 
    21 A^4 Cc C[1]^4 - 14 A B Cc C[1]^4 + 21 A^2 B Cc C[1]^4 - 
    27 A^2 Cc^2 C[1]^4 + 15 A^3 Cc^2 C[1]^4 - 4 A B Cc^2 C[1]^4 - 
    6 A^2 Cc^3 C[1]^4 + 2 A C[1]^5 + 7 A^2 C[1]^5 - 14 A^3 C[1]^5 + 
    5 A^4 C[1]^5 + 2 B C[1]^5 - 3 A B C[1]^5 + A^2 B C[1]^5 + 
    13 A Cc C[1]^5 - 6 A^2 Cc C[1]^5 - 13 A^3 Cc C[1]^5 + 
    3 B Cc C[1]^5 - 4 A B Cc C[1]^5 + 14 A Cc^2 C[1]^5 - 
    12 A^2 Cc^2 C[1]^5 + B Cc^2 C[1]^5 + 4 A Cc^3 C[1]^5 - 
    2 A C[1]^6 + 3 A^2 C[1]^6 - A^3 C[1]^6 - 2 Cc C[1]^6 + 
    3 A^2 Cc C[1]^6 - 3 Cc^2 C[1]^6 + 3 A Cc^2 C[1]^6 - Cc^3 C[1]^6
```

)

I present this as:

[image: Abel ordinary differential equation of the second kind]

Abel ordinary differential equation of the second kind
a[t_]: = (t - t^2) t b[t_]: = -(t - t^2) f[t_]: = A t g[t_]: = A + B + A t h[t_]: = A + C k[t_]: = 0

k has to be unequal zero to identify this. This is in contrast to the Maple result which might be more flexible than Mathematica [DSolve Ordinary Differential Equations](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DSolveOrdinaryDifferentialEquations.html#3584). But if that would be solvable in Mathematica it should work for everybody and not for one.

DEtoolsodeadvisor; gives [_rational, [_Abel, 2nd type, class B]]

There is some inconsistency with Class B if one looks at [odeadvisor%2FAbel2A](https://de.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=odeadvisor%2FAbel2A): there is no Class B in the Maple online documentation for Abel ordinary differential equations.